# Ending Newline Behavior of YAML::parse() with Scalar content written in block form using a literal style

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I have the following YAML file:

```
street:    |
           123 Tornado Alley
           Suite 16
price:     1.47
```

So if I parse that file with `YAML::parse()` from the symfony2 YAML component I expect that I get an array with:

```
string "123 Tornado Alley
Suite 16"
```

in it. But instead of that I get:

```
array (
  'street' => '123 Tornado Alley
Suite 16
'
// ...
)
```

So a determining line break after `Suite 16`.

Is there any reason why the parser behaves like that? To me it looks like a bug...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason of such behaviour is written down in the code. Also you say, this looks to you like a bug. Can you provide more specification why you say so?

Comment: Well after the new line in the YAML file there comes a new key (`price`) so the new line is for separating a key/value pair and not part of the value from de previous key/value pair. That would make more sense for me.

Comment: `YAML::parse()` needs to follow the YAML spec, not what I or you want it to do on occasion. see the answer.

Comment: Of course. But it doesn't make any sense to me. And I just wondered about that spec. So I guess... bad design.

Comment: Well, that's perhaps a problem, just guessing about the design. Reading spec normally gives insight into the design behind, then you can actually say if it's bad, good or ugly. Whatever ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `\n` at the end is not a bug, it must be there.

This is conforming with YAML 1.1 block scalar literal style.

http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#|%20literal%20style/

See also [Example 2.13. *In literals, newlines are preserved*](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id858273).

You might just want to [`rtrim`](http://php.net/rtrim) the data before you continue.

Comment: Okay thx for your link. But is there no way to markup the YAML file that it gets interpreted like it's meant to be? So without a newline at the end? Because if I like to load config YAML file I don't wan't to rtrim() that value each time I use it.

Comment: Why not use flow scalars in double-quoted style then? See [*Example 2.17. Quoted Scalars*](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id858553)

Comment: How would that look like then? Can't find any other solution for newline preserving strings in YAML.

Comment: `hexesc:  "\x13\x10 is \r\n"` <- from that example I've just linked.

Comment: Okay so I've to do the lines manually by adding a `\r\n` then. Strange is, that even if I add something with a `>` which should convert all new lines to spaces I get a line break at the end of the string.

Comment: Well, I bet you can also add newlines by adding `\n` alone. Depends on the newline style you prefer. And yes, it's a block style. And as a block, there must be at least one line-terminator, that is, when the block is of a single line. Otherwise, don't use a block style for your string scalar.

Comment: Okay thx. But there's no possbility to do what I initially expected from the block style? So Writing with line breaks but don't get a line break at the end? If I don't want a line break at the end the only solution is to use flow scalars in double quotes and add the line breaks with `(\r)\n`?

Comment: yes, you should be able to express your very specific string needs best with the double quoted style I'd say. that will also allow you to differ between MAC, DOS or UNIX linebreaks specifically and per each line.